# Did `sudo init 6` cause my file system to be corrupted?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, fsck, corruption

I was developing some code and had open qtcreator (software development IDE), gnome-terminal, and possibly firefox. I needed to restart to test something. So i restarted using `sudo init 6`. When my VirtualBox Fedora 15 VM came back up I got this great error:

```
... unexpected inconsistency run fsck manually fedora ...
```

`fsck` then proceeded to find lots of problems and prompted from my `y` or `n`. After running `fsck` the fedora system has booted up successfully.

**Did `sudo init 6` cause my file system to be corrupted? or was something else the culprit?**

Comment: Should be harmless, did you modify `/etc/inittab` or your init/rc scripts?

Comment: no i did not edit the /etc/inittab

Comment: although i did delete all shared memory... even though some of the shared memory was not owned by my application. (i incorrectly thought that all the shared memory listed via `ipcs -m` was from my app... so that is why i killed all of them)

Comment: where did the error appear, inside the virtual machine or on the host system ? And where did you run sudo init 6, on the virtual machine or on the host ?

Comment: RE - "where did the error appear?": the error appeared when the VM was booting up.

Comment: RE - "where did you run sudo init 6, on the virtual machine or on the host ?": I ran sudo init 6 on the VM.

Comment: is `sudo init 6` the same as using the GUI to click shut down --> click restart?

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith: yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ran `sudo init 6` in the system inside the VirtualBox and that system had corrupted files, then no, `init 6` was not the cause of it. There are plenty of other possible causes though, that you may/should investigate.

If you ran `sudo init 6` in the host OS, and the system inside VirtualBox had file system corruption, then yes, `init 6` was the cause of that. If you suddenly reboot the host system, the virtual ones won't have the chance to umount their filesystems and shutdown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a script for that.

the script needs to do shutdown for guest OS's y reboot the host system.

If the guest OS's are running when you shutdown the system you can get data lost.